# How to detect air blow in microphone using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I tried below code but it is not enough to detect air blow in microphone.

```
// low-pass filter


micPower = ALPHA * instantaneousPower + (1.0 - ALPHA) * micPower;

if (Math.abs(micPower) > 0.01) {
  i++;
  // If low-pass filter condition is fulfilled >= 5 times
  if (i > 5) {
    console.log('user is blowing !');
    document.getElementById('blow').innerHTML = "User is blowing !";
  }
} else {
  i = 0;
  document.getElementById('blow').innerHTML = "";
}
```